# Which message communication pattern is used in generated Vertx Service Proxy classes?

Tags: java, design-patterns, vert.x, event-bus, vertx-verticle

can somebody please **clarify which type of message communication patterns**:

1. Point-To-Point
2. Request-Reply
3. Publish/Subscribe
   ... is **used in GENERATED Vert.X Service Proxy classes** for RESTful CRUD app (which has 4 HttpServerVerticles which communicates with DatabaseVerticle and those are deployed by MainVerticle)?
   Thank you in advance.

I persume it's ***Request-Reply*** since it sends Http Request and recieves Http Response since in "*Vert.x in action*" it states (in **Chapter 3.1.4**):

```
If you need message consumers to get back to the entity that sent the event then go for request-reply.
```

Any help/advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: `Request-Reply`

If you look in the docs for service proxy (https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-service-proxy/java/) you can see in the beginning that it saves you from doing the following "boiler-plate" code:

```java
JsonObject message = new JsonObject();
message.put("collection", "mycollection")
    .put("document", new JsonObject().put("name", "tim"));
DeliveryOptions options = new DeliveryOptions().addHeader("action", "save");
vertx.eventBus().request("database-service-address", message, options, res2 -> {
  if (res2.succeeded()) {
    // done
  } else {
    // failure
  }
});
```

Also from the same link:

> A service is described with a Java interface containing methods
> following the async pattern. Under the hood, `messages are sent on the event bus to invoke the service and get the response back`. But for
> ease of use, it generates a proxy that you can invoke directly (using
> the API from the service interface).

Comment: Thought so too, but only wanted to make sure as other 2 patterns are very similar. Thanks for clearing it up. ;)